# adding sections to first and last in for loop containing sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, liquid

[image: my code]

First of all, I use Plate CMS(runs on shopify liquid), this is creating the `sections` you can see in the image above.

Now im struggeling with a small problem. I want to loop all 6 sections but only 4 of them are placed inside a div and the other 2(the header and footer) are so called `tray's`, meaning there are a bit diffrent and won't be placed inside that div.

I know i can loop through the 4 sections usingsomethign like this:

`$('#mydiv > section').each(function () { /* ... */ });`

but the problem is that i can't select the header and footer this way.
and then i loop on the div above it will loop the `<div data-id="post_15757">` and not the sections inside.

How do i use a loop like this: `$('#mydiv > section').each(function () { /* ... */ });`, but also add my header and footer?

Comment: Looks like you want `$('section')`?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/add/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery add](https://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
let $div = $('#mydiv");
$('> section',$div).add($div.prev()).add($div.next())
```

or in order:

```
let $sections = $('section').first(), $div = $sections.next();
$sections.add($('> section',$div).add($div.next())
```

or perhaps just

```
const $sections = $('section');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also select on data attribute:

```
var sections = $('[data-plate-object="section"]');

$.each(sections, function(idx, val){
    // apply logic
});
```

This makes it almost certain, sections created by the CMS will be selected, and not HTML sections from integration.